# Scatter Plot with different color for positive and negative values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Here is my problem

This is a sample of my two DataFrames (I have 30 columns in reality)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({"Marc":[6,0,8,-30,-15,0,-3],
                   "Elisa":[0,1,0,-1,0,-2,-4],
                   "John":[10,12,24,-20,7,-10,-30]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Marc":[8,2,15,-12,-8,0,-35],
                   "Elisa":[4,5,7,0,0,1,-2],
                   "John":[20,32,44,-30,15,-10,-50]})
```

I would like to create a scatter plot with two different colors : 
1 color if the scores of df1 are negative and one if they are positive, but I don't really know how to do it.

I already did that by using matplotlib

```
plt.scatter(df,df1);
```

And I also checked this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579626/pandas-plot-with-positive-values-one-color-and-negative-values-another) but the problem is that I have two Pandas Dataframe 
and not numpy array as on this link. Hence the I can't use the `c= np.sign(df.y)` method. 
I would like to keep Pandas DataFrame as I have many columns but I really stuck on that.

If anyone has a solution, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the color array in, but it seems to work with 1D array only:

```
# colors as stated
colors = np.where(df1<0, 'C0', 'C1')

# stack and ravel to turn into 1D
plt.scatter(df.stack(),df1.stack(), c=colors.ravel())
```

Output:

[image]